# forwarding error while running on selenium grid

Tags: ruby, selenium-grid

All of a sudden I am confused with selenium grid.

I ran selenium grid with 2 nodes on a windows machine.

Now, I try to run the test from a remote machine on this. It says forwarding error. But if I change the port to 5555, it runs fine. I have tried using the port option while configuring hub. That doesn't work either. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you but I need more details. If I understand you right:

1. the hub is started on machine_1 (say on default port 4444)
2. the nodes are started on machine_2, running something like this:

   ```
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role node -hub http://ip_of_machine_1:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome,maxInstances=5" -port the_port_number (the default is 5555)
   ```
3. you try to run the tests and get forwarding error

Actually this should work. Could you give some more details?